# Test Docker image on Kubernetes, without Docker Daemon

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins, testing

I am new in containers, so I will try to explain my issue as detailed as I can.

I run a Jenkins flow on a Kubernetes agent, that builds a Docker image and push it on a repository. I want to modify the Jenkins flow so the image is tested (some functional tests) before pushed to the repository. I found this project on Github https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/container-structure-test that is convenient for testing, but unfortunately it requires Docker Daemon that is not available on my Kubernetes agent.

Has anyone tried this before? Or does anyone know any workaround? Thanks!

I tried to include a docker container in the pod I use for the Kubernetes agent, create a separate testing file and use this container to run the tests for the image (without the use of the Github project). However, the absence of Docker Daemon is the problem in this case as well.

Answer (score 0):

For running containers inside Jenkins on Kuberntes agents, you can either use [Jenkins Docker in Docker agent](https://www.rokpoto.com/jenkins-docker-in-docker-agent/) or [Jenkins Podman agent](https://www.rokpoto.com/podman-jenkins-agent/) which is a containerless docker alternative with the same cli.

Then, encapsulate tests in a container image and run them inside either of the above agents.

Disclaimer: I wrote above posts.

Also note that there's an option not to use `docker daemon` for the project you mentioned. Use `tar` [driver](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/container-structure-test#running-file-tests-without-docker) instead.